# File Upload Protractor + dropzonejs

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor, dropzone.js

I'm quite new with protractor and I got a project to test that uses Angular and dropzonejs for uploading files. Although I've found a few answers on how to upload a file using protractor, I couldn't figure out how to do that using dropzonejs.
Here is a fiddle of how dropzonejs works [dropzonejs fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/yV8YMMYfcD)

Is there a way to upload files using protractor and dropzonejs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think it is helpful to you:

```
var path = require('path');
    var fileToUpload = 'E:///User/123.jpg';
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
    element(by.css('.file-wrapper')).click();
```

Comment: Couldn't make it work with this. I'm just turning off the validations of uploads in testing, in order to progress with unit test, but I'm not  able to make upload using protractor and dropzonejs yet. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so i had to answer, but Rajana's suggestion worked for me for the most part. I have autoQueue set to true though, so i didn't need the last line (the call to click the upload button) since dropzone automatically handled it. If you do have autoqueue off i believe you will need to trigger the click event for the upload button.

For a while I was running into an issue where i thought the dropzone was working for adding file, but it was forever stuck in a preview state, without the progress bar doing anything. I was confused though since it was displaying the name of my file in the preview. Turns out dropzone was automatically generating filename using the end of the path to the file (which makes sense). But the problem was that I had the file path wrong, and so even though it looked like it was getting my file, because it had the filename in the preview, it wasn't getting any file at all. I checked this by doing alert(file.size) in the "fileadded" dropzone event, which produced a 0.